# SQL JSON Nested Selection

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am trying to improve the performance of a query by not generating the same information twice.

I want to nest some JSON without it adding the JSON under the column name.

The JSON that I want to nest is in stored in another column so my query looks like this:

```
SELECT
        CONCAT(p.branch, p.policyref) AS 'policy_id'
      , p.insurer                     AS 'insurer_code'
      , p.Brand                       AS 'policy_name'
      , p.sale_date                   AS 'sale_date'
      , p.start_date                  AS 'start_date'
      , p.end_date                    AS 'end_date'
      , p.status
      , p.customer_data_json -- This is the column with the other nested JSON
    FROM
        dbo.ic_brpolicy p1
    WHERE
        p.policyref = p1.PolRef@
        AND p.branch = p1.B@
    FOR JSON PATH
```

The column "customer_data_json" is the JSON I wish to nest, however what happens is it nests the JSON under "customer_data_json" because of the column name, however I want to just nest the data without the column name being created.

i.e. This

```
"start_date": "2020-06-20T00:00:00Z",
"end_date": "2021-06-20T00:00:00Z",
"status": "ACTIVE",
"drivers": [{
    "driver_id": "Prop",
    "main_driver": true,
    "app_user": true,
```

instead of

```
"start_date": "2020-02-27T00:00:00Z",
"end_date": "2021-02-27T00:00:00Z",
"status": "ACTIVE",
"customer_data_json": [{
    "drivers": [{
        "driver_id": "Prop",
        "main_driver": true,
        "app_user": true,
```

As you can see because the JSON comes from column "customer_data_json" it nests the information under a "customer_data_json" element and I don't want it to I just want it to begin the "driver" section.

Cheers

Comment: What is the full `$.customer_data_json` JSON content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct statement depends on the structure of the JSON, stored in the `customer_data_json` column, but the following simplified example demonstrates a possible solution:

```
SELECT
   p.start_date AS start_date,
   p.end_date AS end_date,
   p.status AS status,
   JSON_QUERY(p.customer_data_json, '$[0].drivers') AS drivers
FROM
   (VALUES ('2020-02-27T00:00:00', '2021-02-27T00:00:00', 'ACTIVE', '[{"drivers": [{"driver_id": "Prop","main_driver": true,"app_user": true}]}]')
) p (start_date, end_date, status, customer_data_json)
FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
```

Result:

```
{
  "start_date":"2020-02-27T00:00:00",
  "end_date":"2021-02-27T00:00:00",
  "status":"ACTIVE",
  "drivers":[
    {
      "driver_id":"Prop",
      "main_driver":true,
      "app_user":true
    }
  ]
}
```